# NavBar from React Bootstrap doesn't reach end of page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

When the page is in full screen, all my components are shown, with no horizontal scrollbar active, where the NavBar component fills my screen from start to end. But when I adjust the window size and a horizontal scrollbar appears, when scrolled to the right, the NavBar becomes cut off with just white space until the end of the page. Is there a way to extend the NavBar to the end of the page when the scrollbar becomes active? Currently, here is my code for my NavBar

```js
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import "./component.css";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" class="navbar-expand-lg">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
            Financial
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```